# How can I go dismiss two viewcontrollers with navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue, dismissviewcontroller

I have three relevant views, they are all connected to a navigation controller, with push segues (also I have stored arrays using prepare for segue with all three). So I want to use dismiss since I don't want to change the already existing stored arrays that are used in the viewcontrollers.

So I'm at viewcontroller C , and im trying to go back to A.

I have until this point used `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` which works great when dismissing to view B, but I want to go to A.

I have also tried using:

```
let presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController
presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

However this does not work, and produce this error:

> pushViewController:animated: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

Any solution to this?

The reason I want to go to viewcontroller A is because there is a bug in Viewcontroller B when something is updated on Viewcontroller C, so a temporary solution is to just go to A, and reload the tableview.

Comment: Makes no sense. The opposite of push is pop, not dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`setViewControllers(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers) on the navigation controller, passing in an array containing only view controller A. As view controller A is already in the stack, the animation will be a pop.

Alternatively, if you’d rather use segue’s, you can [perform an unwind segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2298/_index.html), back to view controller A.